# Banach contraction theorem with composition

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces, fixed-points

> **Problem 5.** Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathrm{d}_\mathcal{X})$ be a non-empty complete metric space. Suppose that $f,g:\mathcal{X}\longrightarrow\mathcal{X}$ are two Banach's contractions of $\mathcal{X}$. Prove that there always exists a unique point $x_0\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $f\big(g(x)\big)=x_0$.

Dear all,
I am revising for my exam in two weeks by doing old exams. This was a problem in an old exam, but I don't know how to prove this. I guess that f and g need to have the same fixed point in order for this to be true, so I tried to prove this, but I didn't come far. Could anyone please help me with solving this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

They do not need to have the same fixed point—the composition is also a contraction!

I.e., if there exists $λ , μ \in [0,1)$ such that, for all $x,y \in \mathcal X$,

$$d\big(f(x),f(y)\big) \leq λ d\big(f(x),f(y)\big)$$

and

$$d\big(g(x),g(y)\big) \leq μ d\big(g(x),g(y)\big),$$

then, for all $x,y \in \mathcal X$,

$$d\big(fg(x),fg(y)\big) \leq λ \,d\big(g(x),g(y)\big) \leq λ μ \,d\big(x,y\big) $$

This should suffice! I.e., apply the CMT after composing, not before.

Picture:

[image: Two contractions contract]

Comment: I don't understand how to prove that the composition is also a contraction

Comment: I started it for you: look closely at the last inequality

Comment: I understand what happens after the last inequality, but I don't understand why d(f(g(x),fg(y))≤$\lambda$d(g(x),g(y)) holds. Could you please explain this?

Comment: $g(x)$ and $g(y)$ are also in $\mathcal X$, so you can apply all the same relations that apply for $x$ and $y$

Comment: I've also added a quick picture, if that helps